# How to onclick event from a wildcard id inside bootbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQgrid to display a table of data. When I click an icon in a row on the table it properly displays a bootbox with a new table in it. I want the rows to have ids that I can click on that trigger another function via onclick. I am simply trying to get an alert to test but it doesnt seem to work like I am out of scope?? Is it possible to get an onclick event from inside the content of the bootbox that is inside the jqgrid? The bootbox works fine but I cant get an onclick event to fire from clicking an id in the bootbox table.

```
grid.jqGrid({

...

onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
// if column 8 is clicked...
if(iCol==8){

  $('[id^=price-]').click(function(){
    alert('click');
  });

  bootbox.dialog({
    title: 'Popup Title',
    message: '<table><tr><td><span class="label label-lg label-info arrowed" id="price-1234">Match Price</span></td></tr></table></div>',
  });
}
}

...

});
```

Comment: You will want to use jquery on. This allows you to handle events with dynamic HTML. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Are you able to get a demo fiddle running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for listening to events on elements that are not in the DOM yet.

```
$(function(){
   //Handle click events from your selector
   $(document.body).on("click", "[id^=price-]", function(event)
   {
      //Do your logic here.
   });
});
```

Normally you want to make sure you are putting the on handler to the nearest parent. But in this case you are not controlling where bootbox is putting the html(which is in the body) so you have to attach a handler to a higher level on the DOM.